# How to remove touchevent in js?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, touch-event

I'm trying to remove touchevent after the first touch.
I've tried the next code, but it did not work:

```
ourCanvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){
    evt.preventDefault();
    startGame();
    ourGameCanvas.removeEventListener("touchstart");
}, false);`
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a reference to the original function to [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.removeEventListener):

```
ourCanvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function funcref(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    startGame();
    ourCanvas.removeEventListener("touchstart", funcref, false);
}, false);
```

In the previous code, I turned the anonymous function expression in a named function expression (`funcref`) so that it can be used later within the function.

And I renamed `ourGameCanvas` to `ourCanvas`. An event listener can only be removed if the element, event name, function reference *and* useCapture flag are identical to the ones used by [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener).

Answer (score 1):

The `removeEventListener` method expects the same arguments as the `addEventListener` method... in other words:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart',function touchStartHandler(e)
{//use named function
    document.body.removeEventListener('touchstart',touchStartHandler, flase);
},false);
```

Same goes for `attachEvent` and `detachEvent` (in case you're coding to support IE < 9, too)

Comment: This example does not work, because `touchStartHandler` is a **named function expression**, not a **function declaration**. Consequently, the named function is not available outside the scope of the `touchStartHandler` function. (side note: Canvas and touch events are not supported in IE8-, so don't worry about `attachEvent`).

Comment: @RobW I know canvas and touch events aren't supported by IE8, just in case the OP is delegating a click event for non-touch devices or something. On the function reference, you're right of course: the snippet I provided is confusing and incorrect